# Как снять обработчики методом off() в jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На инпут повешено два обработчика для чтения итогового содержимого и посимвольной валидации.

```
let tel;
$("#tel")
    .on("change", function (e) {
      tel = e.target.value;
      return tel;
    })
    .on("input", function (e) {
      e.target.value.replace(/[\s\-]/g, "");
      if (
        e.target.value.match(
          /^((\+?3)?8)?((0\(\d{2}\)?)|(\(0\d{2}\))|(0\d{2}))\d{7}$/
        ) != null
      ) {
        $(".captcha-overlay, .captcha-alert").hide("fast");
      } else {
        $(".captcha-overlay, .captcha-alert").show("fast");
      }
    });
```

Дальше, в зависимости от определённых условий, у этого же инпута должен поменяться набор атрибутов. И нужно, чтобы убрались обработчики, установленные на этом элементе, когда были ещё другие атрибуты. Метод off(), в данном случае, не срабатывает, они всё ещё весят на инпуте с новым набором атрибутов.

```
$("input:not(#try)").show("fast").val("").attr({
          id: "flashcall-code",
          name: "flashcall-code",
          placeholder: "4 цифры входящего",
          onfocus: "hideError()",
        }).off("change input");
```

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что проблема не в том коде, который вы скинули так как он работает правильно. Вот посмотрите: placeholder, name и id успешно изменились, off() убрал change и input

```js
$("#tel")
  .on("change", function() {
    console.log('change');
  })
  .on("input", function() {
    console.log('input');
  });

$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  console.clear();
  $("input:not(#try)").show("fast").val("").attr({
    id: "flashcall-code",
    name: "flashcall-code",
    placeholder: "4 цифры входящего"
  }).off("change input");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="tel" name="fname">
<button id="btn">off</button>
```